# Uniqueness in convergence of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Can a sequence of functions converge to more than one function or is the limit function unique?

Comment: Convergence in what sense? Pointwise? Then no, since limits of real (or complex) numbers are unique.

Comment: And in case of uniform convergence?

Comment: Uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, so again unique limits.

Comment: consider $x_n=(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+1}$, you ca see that $x_{2n}\to 1$ but $x_{2n+1}\to -1$

Comment: @janmarqz This is not a convergent sequence at all (and it particular, it does not converge "to more than one limit": it does not converge to *any* limit). Also, this is not really a sequence of *functions*, unless you mean a sequence of constant functions.

Comment: I am only showing a sequence that has two limit points, with it, can be constructed examples of sequences of functions with the same characteristic :P

Comment: But then they are not convergent. The question asks for uniqueness of the limit: if there is no limit, the question does not apply. ("no limit function" falls into "at most one limit function")

Comment: what about $f_n(x)=(-1)\frac{n}{n+1}x$?

Comment: from the cloud of functions $\{f_n(x)\}$, we can partition as $\{f_{2n}(x)\}$ with $\{f_{2n+1}(x)\}$ such that $\lim f_n(x)=\pm x$, in our example

Comment: @mrf . . perhaps, defining *a sequence is convergent* iff the accumulation points of the sequence is non-void?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple distinct definitions of convergence, usually by specifying a topology on the set of functions one is considering. For example, the space of *all* functions from a set X to a topological space Y can be equipped with the product topology, also knows as "pointwise convergence", i.e., a sequence of functions $f_n:X\to Y$ converges to $f$ if and only if $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ for every point $x$ separately.

If the topology is sufficiently "fine" in the sense that every pair of functions is separated by at least one open set (a.k.a. separation axiom T_0) then limits are unique. Most of the "practical" notions of convergence that you might encounter (pointwise, uniform, ...) satisfy that axiom.

As a counterexample, consider convergence in mean, i.e., we consider the set of all integrable complex-valued functions on the closed interval $[0,1]$ and the "distance" between functions is the integral of their absolute difference. In this set, consider a sequence of functions whose integrals (of their absolute values) converges to zero. That sequence converges to the zero function, but also to any function that differs from the zero function in a finite number of points.